# Are Downloads from file hosting sites are 100% safe from legal issue?

Tags: vpn, torrent

See we can download files from file hosting sites, but there is no warning on it.

but this security warnings present on torrent sites but not on file hosting sites, why so?

See here this picture i encountered. 
[image]

See Another similar case I found :

> In October 2010 Axel Braun
>   Productions filed a complaint regarding with the United States
>   District Court for the Northern District of West Virginia for legal
>   action to be taken against 7,098 individuals who had illegally
>   downloaded the Batman XXX: A Porn Parody through **peer-to-peer** file
>   sharing sites.

see here Axel Braun Productions didn't file complaint
on illegally downloads from file hosting sites, why so?

From this real happened incident, can I declare downloads from file hosting sites  are **100%** safe from legal issue?

Comment: @AndrewT. Most of ISP send legal issue warnings to their customers when they download from peer to peer only.

Comment: There are many logic errors in your question. File hosting companies are also served with copyright infringement notices, but you might not see them because they are served to the hosting company, not you. The Axel Braun article is public, because it involves the public. The notices you see for P2P software are because the average person might not be aware of the line they might cross by *serving* the files.

Comment: Depends on your jurisdiction and what you do with the files. So many ways that this is unanswerable except by suffering direct action for flagrant misuse. You're 100% safe until you are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this question is appropriate for this type of forum however I will answer it regardless.

In peer-to-peer file sharing systems, the peers are responsible for distributing the pirated software.

In non-peer-to-peer file sharing systems, the servers are directly responsible for distributing the pirated software.

Whether it be peers or servers, the distributors are what are targeted, because they are the ones responsible for breaking piracy distribution laws, and it is more efficient to get rid of the distribution than directly going after those benefiting from it. Thus torrenting passes most of the legal responsibility to the client.

Comment: I think, maybe it is. It depends on, can we consider the government as a potential attacker. On my opinion, the answer is clearly yes.